# Count records for previous month SQL

Tags: mysql

Can you help me with a simple task, but I can't really figure out, how I should do that request. Help, please.

I have:

```
doctors
id name             profession 
 1 James Harden     dental 
 2 James Jones      therapist 
 3 LeBron James     cardiologist 
 4 Kobe Braynt      surgeon 
 5 Sabrina Williams nurse 
 6 Tyler Okonma     speech therapist 

patients 
id name         diagnostic 
 1 Mo Bamba     tooth pulling out
 2 Kaney West   astma 
 3 Post Malone  heart attack 
 4 Denzel Curry headache 
 5 Nicola Jokic stomac-ache 
 6 Dwayne Wade  AIDS 

visits
doctorId patientId visitDate 
       1         1 2019-03-09
       2         4 2019-03-01
       2         5 2019-02-26
       2         6 2019-02-05
       3         3 2019-03-03
       4         2 2019-03-07
```

I need to show the doctors serving the largest number of patients in the previous month. I am lost in counting the patients which were serving by doctors. Can you suggest the request, please?

Comment: Can you add schema?

Comment: I hope it's obvious that it makes no sense to store diagnostic in a patients table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group by doctorid` the `visits` table and join to the `doctors` table:

```
select d.name, g.counter
from doctors d inner join (
  select doctorid, count(distinct patientid) counter
  from visits
  where 
    year(visitdate) = year(current_date - interval 1 month)
    and 
    month(visitdate) = month(current_date - interval 1 month)
  group by doctorid
  order by counter desc limit 3
) g on g.doctorid = d.id
order by g.counter desc, d.name
```

You can change `limit 3` to what you like.

Comment: Thank you! it works! You helped me a lot! Can you say, please, what  `count(*)` is ? I mean for `*`.

Comment: I changed it to `count(distinct patientid)` because I think you need how many distinct patients each doctor served. If not leave it like it was. Count(*) counts how many rows exist for each doctorid.

Comment: Count(*) counts the number of visits for each doctor I guess.

Comment: `year(visitdate) = year(current_date - interval 1 month)
    and 
    month(visitdate) = month(current_date - interval 1 month)` I'm struggling to process this little nugget

Comment: @forpas         Yes, that is what I have needed.

Comment: `year(current_date - interval 1 month)` returns the year of the previous month and `month(current_date - interval 1 month)` the previous month

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select d.name, count( distinct v.patientid) noofvisits
from visits v inner join 
    doctors d on v.doctorid=d.doctorid
where v.visitdate < '1-mar-2019'
group by d.name
order by noofvisits desc
```